# Remove gap to Parent Containers Border in Miglayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

first a picture for visualizing the problem 
[image: Gap Removal Problem]

As you can see, there is a huge gap to the parents container on the right and left side of the panel with the arrows, which should not be there. I do not have a clue how to remove the gap. I'm struggling with this for hours, I tried almost everything in the documentation and read all relevant topics on SO and MiG Support Forum. Here is the relevant code:

```
public class ArrowPanel extends JPanel
{

 public ArrowPanel()
 {
     setLayout( new MigLayout( "fill,debug" ) );

     add( new JLabel( Icons.roundArrowRight() ), "grow,wrap" );
     add( new JLabel( Icons.roundArrowLeft() ), "grow" );
 }
}
```

I think this should be easy, but somehow I do not get it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's been a little while since I touched MigLayout but try:

```
"fill, debug, insets 0"
```

Comment: Just setting the insets to 0 worked for me